# how to remove my account,my wishlist in magento account link on home page

Tags: frontend

I want to show only log in and register option in account link which provided
rwd theme in magento 1.9 version.

By default rwd theme show my account,my wishlist, my cart,etc option.

but i dont want all of these just want log in and register option on front end

Comment: Whitelist? Do you mean Wishlist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go to

> app\design\frontend\rwd\yourtheme\layout\customer.xml

```
<!--<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>-->
```

go to

> app\design\frontend\rwd\yourtheme\layout\wishlist.xml

```
<!--<reference name="top.links">
            <block type="wishlist/links" name="wishlist_link" />
            <action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>wishlist_link</blockName></action>
        </reference>-->
```

Comment: if you need after login then add under <customer_logged_in>

Comment: Thanks its working Manoj, and where i can found my cart and check ou option

Comment: <reference name="top.links">
            <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
                <action method="addCartLink"></action>
                <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
            </block>
        </reference>

Comment: app\design\frontend\rwd\yourtheme\layout\checkout.xml

Comment: Thanks Now i want to put image slidder can you help me?

Comment: you are using any extension??